# Is there a way to detect if I'm running on my laptop monitor or external monitor?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a little netbook and when not mobile use it with a 22" monitor.

Now because of the reduced real-estate when running on the laptop monitor it would be good to be able to run a script to change various settings or preferences. Is there a way to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `xrandr`, and see how the output changes depending on whether your monitor is plugged in or not.

On my laptop, the internal display is called "LVDS1" and external is connected on "DVI-0", so I think you can tell based on whether it says "DVI-0 connected" or "DVI-0 disconnected".

This script works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr | sed -n -e '/^[^ ]* connected/{s/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/;p;q}'
```

It assumes that the first screen that says connected is what you want.